# OpenStack Juno and restarting it

Tags: 14.04, juju, openstack

I have installed the openstack deb on ubuntu 14.04 and it all came up and gave me a console full of running VMs and a link to the dashboard and JUJU ...after a reboot I am wondering how I start that all up again?

sorry I used
apted

openstack - Ubuntu Openstack Installer

so it installed everything for me.

Comment: There isn't really enough information on this. What openstack deb did you install? If you used a deb how does Juju fit in to this? What version of the charms do you have? Is this using smashstack?

Comment: it was       openstack - Ubuntu Openstack Installer  so it installed everything

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a Single install --

1. Log into the container

   `sudo lxc-ls -f
   sudo lxc-attach -n <container> # usually something like uoi-bootstrap`
2. Once in the container

   `sudo su - ubuntu
   export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju`
3. Now you can access your juju environment as normal

   `juju status
   juju ssh nova-cloud-controller/0
   ...`

As far as bringing back up the nodes, you'll need to run a `juju status` within the container as above and see which services are reporting errors.

If this is a Multi install --

1. Export the JUJU_HOME on the machine you ran the installer from

   `export JUJU_HOME=~/.cloud-install/juju`

Perform step 3 from above.

Comment: hey thats great seems to have worked  but the /horizon and juju websites arent up...the dashboard I had in the terminal looked like this [link]http://www.merrittnet.org/images/openstack.png

Comment: Does `juju status` output show openstack-dashboard as started? what about apache2?

Comment: openstack-dashboard:
    charm: cs:trusty/openstack-dashboard-9
    can-upgrade-to: cs:trusty/openstack-dashboard-10
    exposed: false
    relations:
      cluster:
      - openstack-dashboard
      identity-service:
      - keystone

Comment: units:
      openstack-dashboard/0:
        agent-state: error
        agent-state-info: 'hook failed: "config-changed"'
        agent-version: 1.20.11.1
        machine: 1/lxc/6
        open-ports:
        - 80/tcp
        - 443/tcp
        public-address: 10.0.4.59

Comment: It failed with `config-changed` hook. Try: `juju resolved --retry openstack-dashboard/0`